# Is it Possible to select the ephemeral port number for any CLient Program in java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, port, client-side

When any client program communicates with server client uses an ephemeral port number to communicate with the server on server port. Is there any way to control/Select the client ephemeral port number in Java.

Comment: From the firewall i need to write this fixed local port rule and also thought it will be good to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you specify the local address / portnumber:

```
Socket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
      Creates a socket and connects it to the specified remote address on the specified remote port.
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29

Comment: @Pavan, localAddress is the address of your local interface (use null if you do not care)

Comment: Does it specify like if i have two network cards which network card to use ?

Comment: How i can reserve this local port. In Linux i think i need to update ip_local_reserverd_ports file how can i handle this in windows ?